# How to create customize View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

How can we create a new `CustomizeViewController` like `UIViewController`, `UITableViewController`, and `etc`...

If anyone having some idea about this please share with us.

Comment: UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController. You can create a new subclass of UIViewController ?

Comment: How to create a basic custom UITableViewController based on a UIViewController: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158367/is-an-uitableview-resizable-can-i-assign-a-different-frame/7158521#7158521

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an view controller from scratch. If you want to create your own view controller, you have to subclass *UIViewController* like,

```
@interface CustomizedViewController : UIViewController
```

And later, if you want to create subclasses of *CustomizedViewController*, simply extend it,

```
@interface FurtherCustomizedViewController : CustomizeViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can we create a new CustomizeViewController like UIViewController

```
UIViewController *CustomizeViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
CustomizeViewController.view = whateverViewYouHave;
```